# Converting UTC timestamp by reference

Tags: r, timezone, utc

I am trying to convert timestamps for multiple airports in the same data set.  The timestamps are imported as UTC – but I want to show each according to its local time zone.  I’m using lubridate, with_tz to convert time zones, and I have a reference data set with time zones for all airports.  But I can not seem to “reference” the time zone field to make the conversion.

I receive a data set for airport data which includes the ICAO airport code (e.g., JFK) and several timestamps.  The data are collected on a central server (Mountain Standard Time - MST), and all the time stamps reflect MST.  Here is a partial data set:

```
ID  airport     timestamp
2342    ATL     4/27/2023  1:26:07 PM
2343    LAX     4/27/2023  2:23:31 PM
```

When I import, R automatically converts to UTC, which is currently MST +6 hours.
Here’s a partial data frame:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c(2342, 2343), 
      airport = c("ATL", "LAX"), 
      timestamp = c('2023-04-27 13:26:07', '2023-04-27 14:23:31'))

ID  airport     timestamp
2342    ATL     4/27/2023  7:26:07 PM
2343    LAX     4/27/2023  8:23:31 PM
```

But I want to show these times in local time (ATL: EST; LAX: PST).   I downloaded a file from the ICAO site that has all the airports and time zones.

Here’s the partial ICAO table:

```
icao <- data.frame(airport = c("ATL", "LAX"), 
                   time_zone_id = c('America/New_York', 'America/Los_Angeles'))

airport     time_zone_id
ATL     America/New_York
LAX     America/Los_Angeles
```

I have done a left join to my dataset to get the time stamps in the same data frame:

```
df1 <- left_join(df, icao, by=c("airport"))

ID  airport     timestamp           time_zone_id
2342    ATL     4/27/2023  7:26:07 PM       America/New_York
2343    LAX     4/27/2023  8:23:31 PM       America/Los_Angeles
```

So now, I should be able to convert the timestamp to local_timestamp:

```
df1 %>% 
  mutate(local_timestamp = with_tz(timestamp, tz = time_zone_id))
```

Instead, I get an error:

> Error in as.POSIXlt.POSIXct(x, tz) : invalid 'tz' value

If I “hard code” for EST, I get the right time for ATL (4 hours earlier than UTC in April), but, of course, the wrong time for LAX (should be 7 hours earlier than UTC):

```
 df1 %>% 
  mutate(local_timestamp = with_tz(timestamp, tz = "America/New_York"))

ID  airport     timestamp           time_zone_id        local_timestamp
2342    ATL     4/27/2023  7:26:07 PM       America/New_York        4/27/2023  3:26:07 PM
2343    LAX     4/27/2023  8:23:31 PM       America/Los_Angeles 4/27/2023  4:23:31 PM
```

I have searched a bit for solutions, but the results are discouraging.  I was hoping someone knew how to change timezones like this “on the fly”, or could suggest another approach?

Comment: Use 'df1 %>% rowwise %>% mutate(....'  instead. Not sure if with_tz vectorizes over tz argument.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit hacky for my taste, but seems to work.

Render timestamps as characters using `strftime`. Can't broadcast `tz` argument so we use `map2_chr` instead. Also gotta cast the timestamp variable to an actual timezone-aware type beforehand. Result is a `character` vector but if it's just for display purposes it would work.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)
library(purrr)

df <- data.frame(ID = c(2342, 2343), 
                 airport = c("ATL", "LAX"), 
                 timestamp = c('2023-04-27 13:26:07', '2023-04-27 14:23:31'))

icao <- data.frame(airport = c("ATL", "LAX"), 
                   time_zone_id = c('America/New_York', 'America/Los_Angeles'))

df1 <- left_join(df, icao, by=c("airport"))


df1 %>% 
  mutate(local_timestamp = map2_chr(as_datetime(timestamp), time_zone_id, ~strftime(.x, format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', tz = .y)))
#>     ID airport           timestamp        time_zone_id     local_timestamp
#> 1 2342     ATL 2023-04-27 13:26:07    America/New_York 2023-04-27 09:26:07
#> 2 2343     LAX 2023-04-27 14:23:31 America/Los_Angeles 2023-04-27 07:23:31
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, Zack!  I'll do more testing, but you're right - it seems to work!